# Looped HTML5 videos are reloaded everytime in iOs

Tags: ios, html, video, parse-platform

I am working on an app based on a WKWebview. In this app, I have several videos displayed with the following HTML5 video tag :

```
<video webkit-playsinline loop poster="url.jpg" data-url='http://parse.com/video.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

Videos are short .mp4 files (500ko to 3mo) and fetched from the Parse Back-end.

As you can see with the "video" tag, videos are looped, which is what I want. The only issue I have is that when a video reaches its end and starts again, it is reloaded, everytime. It means more data will be consumed everytime the video will be looped...

How can I prevent that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that Only once the video is loaded fully or played it will not consume your KB again as the video get stored in the computer cache.

So don't worry your Kb will be consume only once.

Just Like Youtube.

Comment: No, unfortunately, videos are always reloaded in my app once they reach the end when looped... Really annoying. I tried with a UIWebview too and I face the same problem...

Comment: Check your app/Browser cache options are they enabled?

Comment: OK. Just a stupid programming issue with my lazy loading on scroll system. I have just fixed it and it works. I have accepted your answer since you were right : looped videos don't reload by default :-) .